# How to get base url from FTP address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example I have a url like:
ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip

How can I get example.com from this url using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the browser to parse the URL for you like this :

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip';
var host = a.hostname;
```

That gets you the hostname, which in this case would be `ftp.example.com`, if for some reason you have to remove the subdomain, you can do

```
var domain = host.split('.');
domain.shift();
var domain = domain.join('.');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fc5t/)

Here's the different parts to a URL -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#wikiArticle

Answer (score 0):

Here is using javascript `RegExp`

```
input = "ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip";
pattern = new RegExp(/ftp:\/\/\S+?@\S+?\.([^\/]+)/);
match = pattern.exec(input);
alert(match[1]);
```

You can also use `i` at the end of regex to make it case insensitive.

```
pattern = new RegExp(/ftp:\/\/\S+?@\S+?\.([^\/]+)/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like this:

```
var url = "ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip";

var ahref = $('<a>', { href:url } )[0]; // create an <a> element
var host = ahref.hostname.split('.').slice(1).join('.'); // example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a regex to do this for you.

```
url = 'ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip'

base_address = url.match(/@.*\//)[0];
base_address = base_address.substring(1, base_address.length-1)
```

This would contain `ftp.example.com` though. You can fine tune it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to try/add something different (can't bet for performance or the general solution, but it works and hey !  without DOM/regexp involved):

```
var x="ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com/BigFile.zip"
console.log((x.split(".")[1]+ "." + x.split(".")[2]).split("/")[0]);
```

For the given case can be shortest since always will be ".com"

```
console.log(x.split(".")[1]+ ".com");
```

Another (messy) approach (and will work with `.com.something`:

```
console.log(x.substring((x.indexOf("@ftp"))+5,x.indexOf(x.split("/")[3])-1));
```

And well on this we're dependend about having "@ftp" and the slashes "/" (at least 3 of them or one after the `.com.something`) for example would not work with: `ftp://xxx:xxx@ftp.example.com`

**Last update** This will be my best

- without DOM/RegExp, nicer (but also confusing) that the previous ones
- solves the problem about having or don't the slashes,
- still dependant on having "@ftp." in the string.
- works with `.com.something.whatever`

  ```
  (function (splittedString){
      //this is a bit nicer, no regExp, no DOM, avoid abuse of "split" 
      //method over and over the same string

      //check if we have a "/"
      if(splittedString.indexOf("/")>=0){

      //split one more time only to get what we want.
          return (console.log(splittedString.split("/")[0]));
      }
      else{
           return (console.log(splittedString));//else we have what we want
      }

  })(x.split("@ftp.")[1]);
  ```

As always it depends how maintainable you want your code to be, I just wanted to honor the affirmation about there's more than one way to code something. My answer for sure is not the best, but based on it you could improve your question.